# R plot window not displaying ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

Hi all for some reason my plots are not displaying in R.

The code is correct, but its not displaying.

Any ideas why? I tried to produce a pdf but that doesn't work either.

the data set is

```
Date    Site    Al  Cu  pH  Flow
25/09/2014  Bo1 NA  NA  NA  NA
07/10/2014  Bo1 0.1573  0.002   NA  NA
14/10/2014  Bo1 0.1232  0.0004  5.42    NA
04/11/2014  Bo1 0.1111  0.0014  5.12    NA
10/11/2014  Bo1 0.1086  0.0003  5.13    NA
25/11/2014  Bo1 0.8938  0.039   5.28    NA
17/02/2015  Bo1 0.0286  0.0005  7.63    NA
03/03/2015  Bo1 0.0486  0.0001  6.01    NA
17/03/2015  Bo1 0.0467  0.0001  7.65    NA
09/06/2015  Bo1 0.0685  0.0001  5.37    NA
16/06/2015  Bo1 0.0279  0.0022  7.16    NA
30/06/2015  Bo1 0.0833  0.0006  6.27    NA
07/07/2015  Bo1 0.1364  0.0006  4.95    NA
22/07/2015  Bo1 0.1354  0.0011  5.71    NA
01/09/2015  Bo1 0.1327  0.0002  6.32    NA
23/09/2015  Bo1 0.1209  0.0002  5.72    NA
01/12/2015  Bo1 NA  NA  NA  NA
```

The code I use is (sorry, changed a lot so unused packages may be there)

```
rm(list=ls())
    require(ggplot2)
    require(reshape2)
    require(magrittr)
    require(dplyr)
    require(tidyr)
    require(cowplot)
    setwd("~/Documents")
    pdf(file="Bo12.pdf")
    mydata <- read.csv("Metals sheet R2.csv")
    L <- subset(mydata, Site =="Bo1", select = c(Site,Date,Cu))
    L$Date <- as.Date(L$Date, "%d/%m/%Y")
    L$Cu<- as.numeric(as.character(L$Cu))
    I <- ggplot(data=L, aes(x=Date, y=Cu, colour="red")) + 
      geom_point() +
      labs(title = "Total copper in the river Bowydd, 2014-2015
           Bowydd 1 - source.",
           x = "Month 2014/2015",
           y = "Log copper concentration ( mg/L)")  +
      scale_x_date(date_breaks = "1 month", date_labels = "%m") + 
      scale_color_manual(values=c("saddlebrown"), breaks=c('Bo1'))
      theme_get() +
      theme(legend.position="none") 
    r2 <- I + geom_hline(aes(yintercept= 0.0001,  linetype= 'EWFD')) +
      scale_linetype_manual(name = "Limit", values = c(2, 1))+
      theme(legend.position="none")
    r3<- r2 +coord_trans(y = "log10") + annotation_logticks(scaled = FALSE) 
    r4<-r3 + scale_y_continuous(breaks = c(0,0.5,1, 1.5, 2), labels = c(0,0.5,1, 1.5, 2))
    ggdraw(r4) + draw_figure_label(label = "(f)", position ="top.left")
    invisible(dev.off())
plot(r4)
```

Comment: try just `r4` instead of `plot(r4)`?

Comment: This is not reproducible. Also, you are leading a bunch packages you don't use.